# Cors is not authorizing localhost despite being correctly configured

Tags: asp.net-core

I am having a problem with Cors not accepting any localhost connections, I was testing this earlier and it was working fine, I removed the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and now it isn't working anymore no matter what I try:

this is the original method I was using for setting cors policy:

```
app.UseCors(x => x
.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination")
.WithOrigins("http://localhost", "https://localhost", "*", "https://127.0.0.1")
.AllowCredentials());
```

I have also tried:

```
app.UseCors(x => x

.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination")
.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
.AllowCredentials());
```

and

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "policy",
                          policy  =>
                          {
                              policy.AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination")
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
        .AllowCredentials());
                          });
    });

app.UseCors("policy");
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: When you allow ANY origin, you can't use credentials!

Comment: I tried removing it, but still get the same result

Comment: Have you checked the headers? Is "X-Pagination" present? Also origin contains the port used.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I had accidentally changed the debugging mode to IIS Express and it was using a different port to receive requests, that's why CORS was complaining. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Forget it guys, I'm an idiot, I had accidentally changed the debugging mode to IIS Express and it was using a different port to receive requests, that's why CORS was complaining.